# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite - missing “route to server” option

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5, rewrite

(Question moved from StackOverflow)

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate, and have activated IIS (Version 7.5.7600.16385).

I have installed the following modules using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 2.0:

```
* IIS URL Rewrite Module 2
* Microsoft Application Request Routing Version 2 for IIS 7
* Microsoft Web Farm Framework Version 1 for IIS 7
* Microsoft External Cache Version 1 for IIS 7
```

Now I am trying to configure a URL Rewrite rule using the "Route to Server" option. However, in the Edit Inbound Rule page, there is no such option: all I have available are:

```
* Rewrite
* None
* Redirect
* Custom Response
* Abort Request
```

Why is there no "route to server" option ?

**Update:**

I have a "route to server" option for the web-server (top-level configuration for URL Rewrite) but not for the individual sites within that web-server.